# Bedeutungserklärung für "Ausschuss"

Tags: meaning

Das Wort habe ich in der [Verordnung (EU) 2016/679](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/DE/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32016R0679) des Europäischen Parlament und des Rates vom 27. April 2016 gefunden.

> "nach Stellungnahme des Ausschusses der Regionen,"

Im [Wörterbuch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ausschuss) findet man drei verschiedene Bedeutungserklärungen:

1. Austrittsstelle eines Geschosses: der A. war ziemlich groß
2. [zu ↑ ausschießen (3)] für besondere Aufgaben aus einer größeren Gemeinschaft, Körperschaft ausgewählte Personengruppe: ein ständiger A.; ein A. von Expertinnen; ein A. tagt, tritt zusammen; einen A. bilden, wählen; in einen A. gewählt werden.
3. <o.Pl.> [zu ↑ ausschießen (3)] Gesamtheit von fehlerhaften, minderwertigen Produkten, Werkstoffen, Werkstücken, Waren, die aussortiert werden: das ist alles A.

Ich glaube, dass ich die zweite Bedeutungserklärung nehmen sollte, weil der Satz "für besondere Aufgaben aus einer größeren Gemeinschaft" im Kontext die Bedeutung ausspricht. Ich bin aber nicht sicher, was "Körperschaft ausgewählte Personengruppe" mit "für besondere Aufgaben aus einer größeren Gemeinschaft" zu tun hat.

Ich bitte sowohl um eine Bestätigung der Bedeutungserklärung als auch um eine Aufklärung.

Comment: Übrigens ist [(Europäischer) Ausschuss der Regionen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europ%C3%A4ischer_Ausschuss_der_Regionen) ein feststehender Begriff.

Comment: Und übrigens liegen EU-Verordnungen in 24 Sprachen vor.

Comment: Einen Ausschuss kann man auch ein Ko­mi­tee nennen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ja, die zweite Bedeutung ist hier die richtige.

Sie geben dem Komma aber die falsche Bedeutung als Satztrenner, es ist hier aber als Aufzählungszeichen verwendet. Stattdessen könnte man auch schreiben:

> für besondere Aufgaben aus einer größeren [Gemeinschaft oder Körperschaft] ausgewählte Personengruppe

Die eckigen Klammern dienen nur der Verdeutlichung der Zusammengehörigkeit...

Oder anders formuliert:

Eine kleinere Personengruppe, die aus einer grösseren Gruppe (z.B. einer Gemeinschaft oder Körperschaft) für besondere Aufgaben ausgewählt wurde, nennt man Ausschuss.

Answer (score 1):

In diesem Kontext bedeutet das Wort "Gremium", "Kommitee", "Kommission". Vgl. [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremium) und [hier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council).

Auf Englisch würde man "committee", "commission" oder "council" sagen.